# How to mock sub method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'm testing a method which has 4 params. For one of the params which is getting passed I have mocked. But the method I'm testing is also using sub method which I also want to mock since I have tested that particular method before. Below is the illustration of same-

Method in **hello.py** as follows which I'm trying to test -

```
def value_a():
    return a

def abcd_foo(a,b,c,d):
    another_method()
```

Now, in **test.py**, I want to mock `another_method()` when I use `abcd_foo(a,b,c,d)` method -

```
@patch('hello.value_a')
def test_result(self, mock_result_a):         
    mock_result_a.return_value = 'mocking successful of a'
    abcd_foo(mock_result_a.return_value,b,c,d)
```

Now, when using `abcd_foo` it also uses another method `another_mothod()` . So, how to mock `another_method()`.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Let me know if the questions remain uncleared.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do multiple patching

```
    class TestABCDFoo(unittest.TestCase):

        @mock.patch('hello.value_a', return_value='mocking_va')
        @mock.patch('hello.another_method', return_value='mocking_another')
        def test_result(self, mock_value_a, mock_another_method):
            """
            The return_value better to be defined outside the test function with multiple patch
            """
            a = value_a()
            self.assertEqual(a, 'mocking_va')
            result = abcd_foo(a, 'b', 'c', 'd')
            self.assertEqual(result, 'mocking_another')
```